# start conemu with multiple tabs

Tags: conemu

I have 5 different generators.

I've created 5 different tasks in conemu to start a new tab with the name of the generator on the tab and the generator starts immediately.

Now I need to create a script that when conemu doesn't run. ConEmu starts with immediately the 5 tasks started in each there own tab.

How can I start conemu from the command line to start automatically the 5 tasks?

Layout of tasks:

```
10 {generators::generator1}
11 {generators::generator2}
12 {generators::generator3}
13 {generators::generator4}
14 {generators::generator5}
```

Code example in task:

```
%comspec% /k RenameTab "generator one" & "c:\generators\bin\startgen" one
```

And then I like to start it like:

```
ConEmu -tasks 10 11 12 13 14
or
ConEmu -tasks generators::generator1 generators::generator2 generators::generator3 generators::generator4 generators::generator5
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Tasks are described here: https://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html

Answer (score 2):

I've just found it myself, [here](http://conemu.github.io/en/FAQ-6.html#q-6-1)

It works with a startup file and putting the commands inside that file.
That doesn't start the tasks, but it can work for me.

If someone has a method to start the tasks directly it will help ofcourse.